# Is it possible sanity asset make private?

Tags: sanity

Sanity team said "Asset files are not private, so even images uploaded to a private dataset can be viewed by unauthenticated users."
(https://www.sanity.io/docs/keeping-your-data-safe)

The material on my site is only viewable by those who pay a monthly fee.

The material is mainly a pdf file.
Uploading a pdf file with type="file" creates an asset url.
Anyone can view it by typing the path into a web browser.

In the case of Vimeo, videos are played only when accessing from a specific domain.
Similarly, is it possible to make sanity assets available only within a specific domain?

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation and have done some resarch. It seems like private assets can't exist on Sanity. I believe the main reason is that every asset under 10MB in size will be cached on a CDN which does not have the authentication logic required to protect the assets.

IMO they should provide a toggle to make certain assets private, with the disclaimer that it will not be cached on a CDN.

Read more about Sanity CDN: https://www.sanity.io/docs/asset-cdn

EDIT:
You can however use a custom asset source, but it doesn't really sovle the problem: https://www.sanity.io/docs/custom-asset-sources